# Header divs with fixed position lose width and display above root container's border

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to create a table with a fixed header inside a vertically scrolling div. The table has fixed column widths so creating the header divs at the right size was not a problem.

[image]

However, when I apply the `position: fixed` attribute to the header div's styles the div's become only as wide as their text.

[image]

The div's behave exactly as I want them to, in terms of letting the table scroll below them, but their backgrounds are all off. I attempted to correct this by explicitly setting their width and setting their `left` and `right` style properties to `0` but neither of those attempts worked.

Another issue I'm facing is that the div's overflow the root container's border creating this undesired look on the upper left corner:

[image]

The corner should look like this

[image]

The code snippet for my divs and table is below:

```css
.scrollBars {
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 2px solid #6ba8cf;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.scrollingTable {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.scrollingTable td {
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 4px;
  border: none;
}
.scrollingTableHead {
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0px;
  height: 45px;
}
.scrollingTableHead > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.scrollingTableHead > div > div {
  padding: 10px 2px;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #0054A0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollBars">
  <div class="scrollingTableHead">
    <div style="width: 10%;">
      <div>
        &nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 30%;">
      <div>
        Name
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 30%;">
      <div>
        Title
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 30%;">
      <div>
        Department
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <table class="scrollingTable">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:10%;"><a href="">Select</a>
      </td>
      <td style="width:30%;">AAAAAAAA</td>
      <td style="width:30%;">AAAAAAAA</td>
      <td style="width:30%;">AAAAAAAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:10%;"><a href="">Select</a>
      </td>
      <td style="width:30%;">BBBBBBBB</td>
      <td style="width:30%;">BBBBBBBB</td>
      <td style="width:30%;">BBBBBBBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:10%;"><a href="">Select</a>
      </td>
      <td style="width:30%;">CCCCCCCC</td>
      <td style="width:30%;">CCCCCCCC</td>
      <td style="width:30%;">CCCCCCCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:10%;"><a href="">Select</a>
      </td>
      <td style="width:30%;">DDDDDDDDD</td>
      <td style="width:30%;">DDDDDDDDD</td>
      <td style="width:30%;">DDDDDDDDD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:10%;"><a href="">Select</a>
      </td>
      <td style="width:30%;">EEEEEEEE</td>
      <td style="width:30%;">EEEEEEEE</td>
      <td style="width:30%;">EEEEEEEE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:10%;"><a href="">Select</a>
      </td>
      <td style="width:30%;">FFFFFFFF</td>
      <td style="width:30%;">FFFFFFFF</td>
      <td style="width:30%;">FFFFFFFF</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like tabular data: I'd use an actual table for it. But, why are you applying position fixed to each individual heading div, instead of the div that contains all the headings? If you use a table approach instead, and split your table into thead and tbody, you can apply the overflow-y style only to the tbody.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser I attempted to get your solution to work using [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c735vb9e/1/) but it doesn't appear like the `overflow` property works on the `tbody`.